# How to remove selection from table?

Tags: angular, typescript, primeng

I've been struggling with this for a while now. I have a simple table and when I select a row it gets **selected**. But I want to add a functionality to my button (**remove Selection**) so that when I click on it I want to remove the selection from the row. Can someone tell me what I'm missing? Thanks a lot in advance!

Here's my code:
[**LIVE DEMO**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-b1gx4b?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)

```
 <p-table [value]="tableData" selectionMode="single" metaKeySelection = "true">
<ng-template pTemplate="header">
    <tr>
        <th>Company</th>
        <th>First Name</th>
        <th>Email</th>
    </tr>
</ng-template>
<ng-template pTemplate="body" let-rowData let-rowIndex="rowIndex">
    <tr [pSelectableRow]="rowData">
        <td>{{rowData.first_name}}</td>
        <td>{{rowData.last_name}}</td>
        <td>{{rowData.email}}</td>
    </tr>
</ng-template>
</p-table>

<button (click)= "removeSelection()">Remove Selection</button>
```

Comment: Glad to know that my answer works!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have to add the `[(selection)]="selectedRow"` in the `p-table` in order to bind the selected row to the variable that you have defined:

```
<p-table [value]="tableData" selectionMode="single" metaKeySelection = "true" [(selection)]="selectedRow">
<ng-template pTemplate="header">
    <tr>
        <th>Company</th>
        <th>First Name</th>
        <th>Email</th>
    </tr>
</ng-template>
<ng-template pTemplate="body" let-rowData let-rowIndex="rowIndex">
    <tr [pSelectableRow]="rowData">
        <td>{{rowData.first_name}}</td>
        <td>{{rowData.last_name}}</td>
        <td>{{rowData.email}}</td>
    </tr>
</ng-template>
</p-table>

<button (click)= "removeSelection()">Remove Selection</button>
```

And also add the `this.selectedRow = null;` in the `removeSelection()` method:

```
removeSelection() {
    this.selectedRow = null;
}
```